# Word - Reflecting Events

Tags: events, reflection, ms-word

I am trying to use reflection to get all the events in word and then create a delegate that I can add to one of these events. The code I have so far is:
Thanks for the response.

Well the idea is to pass the name of an event such as DocumentBeforeSave to a method a bit like:

```
EventInfo p = getEvent(this.Application, "DocumentBeforeSave");

public EventInfo getEvent(Word.Application wordApp, string eventName)
    {
      Type wordType = wordApp.GetType();

      EventInfo[] f = wordApp.GetType().GetEvents();
      EventInfo result = (from o in f
                where o.Name == eventName
                select o).FirstOrDefault();
      return result;
    }
```

Now this gives me an EventInfo of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler. Which to me looks like Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforePrintEventHandler which can assign and eventhandler with +=;

I see that the EventInfo has an AddEventHandler method. I am hoping that I can attach my own delegate to handle when the DocumentBeforeSave event fires.

The problem is, I just don't seem to be able to get the delegate right. I have been playing around with this:

```
    MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo = msw.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
          MethodInfo r = (from o in myArrayMethodInfo
                  where o.Name == "add_" + p.Name
                  select o).FirstOrDefault();

Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(p.EventHandlerType,r, false);
```

But the Delegate is always null. Is this just not possible or am I just doing it wrong.

Thanks

Comment: msw is defined like this:  Word.Application ms = (Word.Application)this.Application;
Type msw = ms.GetType();

Comment: These are COM events. They work differently.  Also, creating a Delegate for the adder method won't do you any good.  Plus, that's the wrong delegate type for the adder; it would need an `Action<EventHandlerType>`.

Comment: Ahh right so this is totally wrong. Do you think this is even possible then?

Comment: Yes, it is.  You need to create expression trees.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [Expression Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

This feature allows you to compile code at runtime into an arbitrary delegate type.

Comment: Hi, I have no experience of expression trees but have clarified the situation a bit more so hopefully you can see what I am trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @user: You need to get some experience with expression trees.  They're the easiest way to create an arbitrary delegate method with arbitrary parameters.  You can also use ILGenerator, but that's much harder.

Comment: You haven't clarified the situation at all.

Comment: Hi thanks again. I am trying to write one method that I can use to add eventhandlers to just about any word event. Does that make more sense?

Comment: If you don't know the parameters passed to the event, you'll need to use expression trees.